# Elegant way to report missing values in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

Here's a little piece of code I wrote to report variables with missing values from a data frame.  I'm trying to think of a more elegant way to do this, one that perhaps returns a data.frame, but I'm stuck:

```
for (Var in names(airquality)) {
    missing <- sum(is.na(airquality[,Var]))
    if (missing > 0) {
        print(c(Var,missing))
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm dealing with data.frames with dozens to hundreds of variables, so it's key that we only report variables with missing values.

Comment: @kohske: that was my first thought, but the results are a `table` of characters and you would have to parse out the number of NAs.

Comment: I'm reverting your question, since you posted an answer.  If you want to comment on an answer, please do so as a comment to that answer.  If questions also contains answers, this becomes very confusing.

Comment: @Andrie: I disagree with your edit, as a key issue I am facing is reporting only variables with missing values.  Furthermore, your rollback removed a change I made to the code. I've edited my question to include this information, and added my modified version of Josh's code to a comment.

Comment: @Zach Your new edit looks fine to me.  I'm not averse to adding additional data / requests in a question once it's live, by the way, if this clarifies the question.

Comment: There are half a million ways to do this, see [CRAN Task View - MissingData](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Just use `sapply`

```
> sapply(airquality, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
     37       7       0       0       0       0
```

You could also use `apply` or `colSums` on the matrix created by `is.na()`

```
> apply(is.na(airquality),2,sum)
  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
     37       7       0       0       0       0
> colSums(is.na(airquality))
  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
     37       7       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: I modified your code slightly, to only report missing value: `M <- sapply(airquality, function(x) sum(is.na(x))); 
M[M>0]`

Comment: Thanks! Learned a lot.

Comment: Hi @Joshua Ulrich , thanks a lot for your succinct code. I would like to add a column in the data frame which would show the percentage of na values . Can you please provide some help regarding this ?

Comment: @Zach I use a version of your suggestion for checking that required fields have a value:
`M <- colSums(is.na(airquality)); M[M <= 0]`

Comment: @Joshua adding an option for %s would be ace too!

Answer (score 9):

My new favourite for (not too wide) data are methods from excellent [naniar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar) package. Not only you get frequencies but also patterns of missingness:

```
library(naniar)
library(UpSetR)

riskfactors %>%
  as_shadow_upset() %>%
  upset()
```

[image]

It's often useful to see where the missings are in relation to non missing which can be achieved by plotting scatter plot with missings:

```
ggplot(airquality,
       aes(x = Ozone,
           y = Solar.R)) +
 geom_miss_point()
```

[image]

Or for categorical variables:

```
gg_miss_fct(x = riskfactors, fct = marital)
```

[image]

These examples are from package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/naniar-visualisation.html) that lists other interesting visualizations.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! There is now a dedicated `gg_miss_upset()` function in the latest release, which will be submitted to CRAN once they return from holiday.http://naniar.njtierney.com/reference/gg_miss_upset.html

Answer (score 8):

We can use `map_df` with purrr.

```r
library(mice)
library(purrr)

# map_df with purrr
map_df(airquality, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# A tibble: 1 × 6
# Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
# <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    37       7     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: What's the advantage of `map_df` over `sapply`?

Comment: @Zach I think that there is no big difference, but Hadley said not to use sapply() inside a function. See Exceptions and debugging · Advanced R. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html.

Comment: for lazy people like me, you can write the above code in shorter purrr syntax for functions (~) so it looks like this: `map_df( air quality, ~sum(is.na(.) )`

Comment: @Zach the advantage of `map_df` over `sapply` is only when the result has many rows as the output format of map_df is always a tibble.

Comment: @Zach: it's better to use `vapply` vs `sapply` in functions because `vapply` gives you a known result structure (that you specify). `sapply` may return an array or a list, depending on the function output. A disadvantage of `map_df` is that you give it a data.frame as input, and it returns a data.frame subclass, not a data.frame. There's no guarantee that tibbles will behave as data.frames do in all necessary cases in the future.

Answer (score 6):

```
summary(airquality)
```

already gives you this information

The **VIM** packages also offers some nice missing data plot for data.frame

```
library("VIM")
aggr(airquality)
```

[image]

Comment: Can the VIM package report which specific observations have missing data?

Comment: don't think so.. but you can get this quite easy (you would have to replace airquality with your own dataframe): res <- airquality[rowSums(is.na(airquality)) > 0,]

Answer (score 5):

Another graphical alternative - `plot_missing` function from excellent `DataExplorer` package:

[image]

[Docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/vignettes/dataexplorer-intro.html) also points out to the fact that you can save this results for additional analysis with `missing_data <- plot_missing(data)`.

Comment: The `plot_missing()` function in the `DataExplorer` package is now `PlotMissing()`.

Comment: @coip `PlotMissing()` is deprecated. Please use `plot_missing()` instead. See [#49](https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/issues/49) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

More succinct-: `sum(is.na(x[1]))`

That is

1. `x[1]` Look at the first column
2. `is.na()` true if it's `NA`
3. `sum()` `TRUE` is `1`, `FALSE` is `0`

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question, which is to find the number of `NA`s for *all* columns in the data

Answer (score 2):

Another function that would help you look at missing data would be df_status from funModeling library

```
library(funModeling)
```

iris.2 is the iris dataset with some added NAs.You can replace this with your dataset.

```
df_status(iris.2)
```

This will give you the number and percentage of NAs in each column.

Answer (score 2):

For one more graphical solution, `visdat` [package](https://github.com/ropensci/visdat) offers `vis_miss`.

```
library(visdat)
vis_miss(airquality)
```

[image]

Very similar to `Amelia` output with a small difference of giving %s on missings out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Amelia library does a nice job in handling missing data also includes a map for visualizing the missing rows.

```
install.packages("Amelia")
library(Amelia)
missmap(airquality)
```

[image]

You can also run the following code will return the logic values of na

```
row.has.na <- apply(training, 1, function(x){any(is.na(x))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another graphical and interactive way is to use `is.na10` function from `heatmaply` library:

```
library(heatmaply)

heatmaply(is.na10(airquality), grid_gap = 1, 
          showticklabels = c(T,F),
            k_col =3, k_row = 3,
            margins = c(55, 30), 
            colors = c("grey80", "grey20"))
```

[image]

Probably won't work well with large datasets..

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution to get the count could be:

```
summarise_all(df, ~sum(is.na(.)))
```

Or to get a percentage:

```
summarise_all(df, ~(sum(is_missing(.) / nrow(df))))
```

Maybe also worth noting that missing data can be ugly, inconsistent, and not always coded as `NA` depending on the source or how it's handled when imported. The following function could be tweaked depending on your data and what you want to consider missing:

```
is_missing <- function(x){
  missing_strs <- c('', 'null', 'na', 'nan', 'inf', '-inf', '-9', 'unknown', 'missing')
  ifelse((is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.infinite(x)), TRUE,
         ifelse(trimws(tolower(x)) %in% missing_strs, TRUE, FALSE))
}

# sample ugly data
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, '1', '  ', 'missing'),
                 b = c(0, 2, NaN, 4),
                 c = c('NA', 'b', '-9', 'null'),
                 d = 1:4,
                 e = c(1, Inf, -Inf, 0))

# counts:
> summarise_all(df, ~sum(is_missing(.)))
  a b c d e
1 3 1 3 0 2

# percentage:
> summarise_all(df, ~(sum(is_missing(.) / nrow(df))))
     a    b    c d   e
1 0.75 0.25 0.75 0 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for particular column, then you can also use this

```
length(which(is.na(airquality[1])==T))
```

Comment: You don't need to compare a logical vector to T. You can also count the number of TRUE elements in a logical vector by summing it.

Answer (score 0):

ExPanDaR’s package function [`prepare_missing_values_graph`](https://joachim-gassen.github.io/ExPanDaR/reference/prepare_missing_values_graph.html) can be used to explore panel data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For piping you could write:

```
# Counts 
df %>% is.na() %>% colSums()

# % of missing rounded to 2 decimals 
df %>% summarise_all(.funs = ~round(100*sum(is.na(.))/length(.),2))
```