# Losing my Decimals after performing operation

Tags: r, decimal, missing-data, read.csv

I'm facing a problem that I cannot fix. I have not a lot experience in R so any help will be welcome.

Okay so I have a variable called `supermarkt2015_afst` which is the distance to the supermarket. It goes from 0.1 towards 99.9. km. 
However the variable contains some MISSING values.

Since the fields are literally called `"MISSING"` and I don't want anything above 100km I clean it by;

```
datamodel2 <- datamodel2 %>% mutate(supermarkt2015_afst=ifelse(supermarkt2015_afst=="MISSING",NA,supermarkt2015_afst))

datamodel2 <- datamodel2 %>% mutate(supermarkt2015_afst=ifelse(supermarkt2015_afst>100,NA,supermarkt2015_afst))
datamodel2 <- datamodel2 %>% filter(!is.na(supermarkt2015_afst))
```

This cleans indeed the MISSING values and throws away roughly a third of my observations. Which is exactly what I wanted. HOWEVER. The variable now goes from 2-99. Not like 2.1 2.2 2.3, only round numbers. Where did it all go wrong? It says my variable is Integer when I run "typeof". What i want is have the same accuracy as before on 1 decimal. But for some reason it alters my variable as well.

---

One variable in my data looks like

```
dput(head(datamodel2$supermarkt2015_afst)) 

structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0,1", "0,2", "0,3", "0,4", "0,5",
 "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", "1,0", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,4", 
"1,5", "1,6", "1,7", "1,8", "1,9", "10,0", .............. "6,4", "6,5", "6,6",
 "6,7", "6,8", "6,9", "7,0", "7,1", "7,2", "7,3", "7,4", "7,5", "7,6", "7,7", 
"7,8", "7,9", "8,0", "8,1", "8,2", "8,3", "8,6", "8,9", "9,0", "9,1", "9,2", 
"9,3", "9,6", "MISSING"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: You accidentally converted this field to a factor when you read it in, and the numbers have been replaced by the integer factor codes.  How are you reading in your data?  See the `na` argument to `readxl::read_excel` or `readr::read_csv` or `na.strings` for `read.csv`

Comment: # Read CSV into R
cbsdata <- read.csv(file="data2015.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
attach(cbsdata)

Comment: Is that what you meant? And how can I fix it? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(cbsdata, 20))` in your question?

Comment: That is a lot to paste in. What are you looking for?

Comment: I ran for the variable itself since the output was HUGE. This is before cleaning. Left some numbers out as it 2 long

> dput(head(datamodel2$supermarkt2015_afst))
structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0,1", "0,2", 
"0,3", "0,4", "0,5", "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", "1,0", "1,1", 
"1,2", "1,3", "1,4", "1,5", "1,6", "1,7", "1,8", "1,9", "10,0", 
.............. "6,4", "6,5", "6,6", "6,7", "6,8", "6,9", "7,0", "7,1", "7,2", 
"7,3", "7,4", "7,5", "7,6", "7,7", "7,8", "7,9", "8,0", "8,1", 
"8,2", "8,3", "8,6", "8,9", "9,0", "9,1", "9,2", "9,3", "9,6", 
"MISSING"), class = "factor")

Comment: After cleaning it looks like.

dput(head(datamodel2$supermarkt2015_afst))
c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)

sorry for the posts, but doesnt fit in one.

Comment: as Ben Bolker suggests, you could use the `na.strings` argument when reading in , so try `cbsdata <- read.csv(file="data2015.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings=c("", "MISSING"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: I now did it load in as Ben Bolker suggested. 
And yes this replaces my "missing" with NA. 
But this does not solve the problem. Because now I can't clean my data. Because when I run    

datamodel2 <- datamodel2 %>% mutate(supermarkt2015_afst=ifelse(supermarkt2015_afst>100,NA,supermarkt2015_afst))
datamodel2 <- datamodel2 %>% filter(!is.na(supermarkt2015_afst))

I end up with 0 observations 

Warning message:
In Ops.factor(supermarkt2015_afst, 100) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: oh, I just noticed from your comment, your data is using commas for the decimal separator - so also use `dec=","` in `read.csv`

Comment: However cleaning the NA's worked. I still have the decimals. It's just. I can't cut off all variables >100 cause factor....

Comment: I think that did the trick man. I'm going to run some checks to be sure first.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work. You are a hero. And Ben thanks too and for everyone who have helped.

One more thing though.
I cannot see how many NA's i have per variable.
this is important for me so i know how many observations i lose per adding variable.

I run

> sum(is.na(datamodel2$ziekenhuis_incl2015_afst))
[1] 94627
> sum(is.na(datamodel2$supermarkt2015_afst))
[1] 94627

but those are the total NA's. not per variable. Anyone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317231/elegant-way-to-report-missing-values-in-a-data-frame

Comment: `sapply(df, function(x) table(is.na(x))[["TRUE"]])` Number of NAs per column or variable.

Comment: I get > sapply(datamodel2$supermarkt2015_afst, function(x) table(is.na(x))[["TRUE"]])
Error in table(is.na(x))[["TRUE"]] : subscript out of bounds
>

Comment: @Thundersheep ; you dont use `sapply` directly on a single variable, you use it on the dataset - it loops across each variable. So use `sapply(datamodel2, ...` . But please look at the link i gave there are better ways to do this.

Comment: yes (e.g. `sapply(datamodel2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))`)

Comment: Yeah okay ran it like Ben said now. That works. But it gives the same output for all variables. Or well half of them say 0, so nothing missing and those who miss are all 67.195

Comment: Never mind think I found a solution. Anyway great thanks to you all!