# Excel Difference using Python - openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a scenario where I need to compare two excel files with millions of rows and find the difference in data after comparing every cell between two workbooks.

Here's the code I have written so far -

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

data_file1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test1.xlsx")
data_file2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test2.xlsx")

fill_style = PatternFill(start_color="FDD835", end_color="FDD835", fill_type="solid")

data_sheet1 = data_file1['Sheet1']
data_sheet2 = data_file2['Sheet1']

for row in data_sheet1.rows:
    for cell in row:
        current_cell_value = cell.value
        cell_location = cell.coordinate

        if current_cell_value != data_sheet2[cell_location].value:
            cell.fill = fill_style

data_file1.save("compared_file.xlsx")
```

This is working fine if there are no gaps between two workbooks, but my workbooks have gap in them. To further explain - First column in my workbook is timestamp which increments every second, and all other columns gives the data for any specific timestamp. Now, there is a possibility that one of the workbook could skip few seconds in between, therefore missing the entire rows for those particular timestamp. Example: one sheet continues data entries from 1:00:00 till 1:00:10; while the other sheet could skip couple of seconds (rows) and then continue (1:00:00 to 1:00:04 --> 1:00:07 to 1:0010). Once that happens, my code from thereon mismatches all the following rows as it didn't consider the gap.

How can I make my code consider this gap looking at the timestamp and then address that gap and then continue comparing remaining rows for data entries on other columns keeping timestamp as a reference?

I hope I'm able to explain. Please let me know if there are any questions. Appreciate any help. Thank you!

[Gap Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULXH1.png)

Comment: please format your code (I cant edit right now)

Comment: the way I would do that is to load all data into pandas. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Hi. We understand your question. But in the spirit of [ask] and [mre], please provide a small sample that is representative of your data and problem.

Comment: by the way, millions of rows + row by row loop : how long is the computation? indeed as @julaine suggests, how about passing by pandas, joining dataframes by time, then comparing rows using a vectorized method. Join example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69275059/12846804

Comment: @OCa I have added a link to represent a gap I'm talking about. Please have a look.

Comment: @julaine I have not looked into pandas, never used it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the missing value in an excel table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755989/check-the-missing-value-in-an-excel-table). Best hit I can find about very similar issue recommends pandas too,... or, outside Python, R.

Comment: openpyxl.load_workbook has no optional argument about not skipping empty rows? I was first looking at this but could not find it.

Comment: These workbook sheets. Can you provide a relevant portion of them in text inside the post? Rather than as a picture, so it may be used. With columns names if they exist. Generally, no pictures whenever possible.